# Have a specific character be display at the beginning of a sketch in Processing

Tags: processing, typography

My sketch displays a pressed keyboard letter on the screen. i.e. I press "q", and that will show if I press "p", "q" will be change to "p" and so for.

One character at a time. However, when I run the program, it starts with a blank page. I want to be able to run it, and it would start displaying an "a" for example, then if I pressed any other character, it would change automatically to that one and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store that character in a variable, and then simply display it on the screen. You might also have another variable that keeps track of whether the user has typed anything- a `boolean` might do the trick here.

Alternatively, you could try setting the `key` variable directly, but I'm not sure how well that's going to work.

The point is you need to try something and post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you get stuck, and we'll go from there. Good luck.